# What does the word "high" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Klein student punished for being high despite squeaky clean drug test

What does the word **high** here really mean?

Comment: While "squeaky clean" is simple enough to look up with a quick web search for nothing more than "define squeaky clean", high is not so easy.

Comment: Still, the correct definition of "high" is in the dictionary, especially since we know that it has something to do with drugs.  **12 b :  intoxicated; also :  excited or stupefied by or as if by a drug** (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high)

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "high" means "high on drugs".  In other words, "intoxicated".

Answer (score 1):

Saw this [answer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=high) in Urban Dictionary:

> "after smoking some bud, this feeling washes upon you like a warm wave. The first notic[e]able sign you get is when everything takes on a hazy effect. It[']s like, a weight being lifted off your shoulders. Then you get the giggles. Everything seems to be funny. And if you can't control yourself, it[']s difficult to stop."

Most likely, the student's actions are the same as above described, but keep in mind that there are different kinds of drugs - uppers, downers, etc. (different drug, different effect.) Or perhaps the student is psychologically unstable. Haven't seen the news/source.